# drop down spinner selected item bias

Tags: java, android

This is my problem

Spinner selected view bias ....

Here is the image

[image: Screenshot]

exist long text in unselected item than bias selected view ...

I suffer ... please help me ...

This is Selected item

I try to `ConstraintLayout -> RelativeLayout`

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selected_habit"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:paddingStart="58dp"
    android:paddingEnd="58dp"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/habit_spinner_state"
    android:layout_width="15dp"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/selected_habit"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_habit_spinner_closed"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="124dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

This is unselected item

```xml
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/selected"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/habit"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_habit_selected"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/habit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingStart="58dp"
        android:paddingEnd="58dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextWhite"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/complete"
        android:layout_width="14dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="26dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/habit"
        android:src="@drawable/habit_complete_icon"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="124dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"/>
```

This is `Spinner`

```xml
<com.crew.d.habit.ui.view.DropDownSpinner
    android:id="@+id/habit_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:overlapAnchor="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:popupBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: I made a specific list using the drop-down spinner.
However, when the sentence of the drop down spinner item gets longer, the selected item is shifted to the left.

Comment: @Edric help me!